# Reloading a page via AJAX when window.location=self.location doesn't work

Tags: javascript, browser, caching, reload

On my homepage I got:

```
<ul id="login">
  <li> <a id="loginswitch" href="./login-page">log-in</a> | </li>
  <li> <a id="signupswitch" href="./signup-page">sign-up</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Via MooTools, I get these anchor elements by id so that once they're clicked, a flashy div will popup below them that contains the login or signup form (with methods to stop the propagation of events of course)
and upon filling-up the fields the AJAX call kicks in - that's supposed to create a session and reload the page so that the user would have a visual that he is now logged in and user-level-controls appears etc..

The ajax call is initiated by the MooTools AJAX class and `evalScripts` option is set to true. The AJAX page returns the script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location = self.location;</script>
```

This system works perfectly - now I'm wondering why if I change the anchors' `href` values to `href="#"` my scripts won't work anymore?

Does it have anything to do with the window?

Did it change its property when I clicked a link or so even when the event's propagation was stopped??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
window.location = self.location;
```

**This JavaScript is executing**.

When it executes, the browser is being told to replace the value of `window.location` with a new value.  **Not all browsers** will react the same way here. Some will probably work as you expect, but others will get smart about it and compare the two values.  **The browser knows** what page it's on, and it knows that you're just asking for it to go to the same page.

**Browser Cache**

The browser even has a copy of your current page in **cache**.  It can talk to the server and ask whether the page it has in cache is still valid.  If the cache is valid, it may decide not to force a reload of the page.  Behind the scenes, this happens with HTTP headers.  Browsers and servers can communicate over HTTP in many ways.  In this case, your browser sends a quick request to the server saying something like this:

```
GET /stackoverflow.com/posts/196643/index.html
HTTP/1.1
Host: www.stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
If-Modified-Since: Sun, 12 Oct 2008 20:41:31 GMT
```

This is called a **conditional GET request**.  By saying *If-Modified-Since*, your browser is saying, "Give me that file, but only if it has been modified since the last time I saw it."

Long story short, you haven't explicitly told the browser to reload the page.

**Here's how you can:**

```
location.reload( true );
```

The "true" is an **optional parameter**, for **forcing a reload**.  The browser won't even look at the cache. It will just do as you say.

Answer (score 1):

Going to an anchor on a page -- which is what `#` signifies -- does not require a reload.

Answer (score 0):

If they handed me this particular task at work I'd kick it back to design.  Unless we're talking about a secure page, or an OpenID login, you should not pop up a log-in or sign-in form.  Users need to learn to look for that https: at the top of their page, and never sign in if they don't see it.